# Do we really need [body parts]?

Tags: discussion, tags

There's a tag [body-parts](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/body-parts) on the main site. Is this *really* necessary, or can we burninate it?

Comment: (and yes, I did post this mainly for the title) :-P

Comment: its always easier to ask forgiveness than permission. Its even easier to ask for neither.

Comment: Ah... I'd hoped for a title like: "Can we burn [body-parts]?" :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it's absolutely not necessary, and doesn't even come close to meeting the criteria for a good tag.

Or, what I should probably say is... what [body-parts](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/body-parts)?